# How to get Custom date format from timestamp php

Tags: php, date

I have a time stamp like this code below.

```
$time=time();
```

Please Explain how can i make a custom date from this.

Comment: [date — Format a local time/date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use php builtin date function like this.

```
$time=time();
$custom_date=date('Y-m-d',$time);
echo $custom_date;
```

i hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )

As an example:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', $time);
```